# Why does moment/torque equal to force multiplied by distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment

moment  is equal to force x distance but why is is it so. why is it so that greater the distance less the effort needed? i tried understanding it mathematically but it just went over my head. if any body can explain it in any other way ,i would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you ever used a lever to pry something open? It gives you firsthand experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the case when you are trying to push something first. The work done over the pushing distance is equal to the Kinetic Energy at the end.  $$F\Delta{x} = W = \Delta{KE}$$

So, you could spend the same amount of energy if you apply a large force over a small distance or if you apply a small force over a large distance. If there are no external forces then the work done (or energy spent by you) is equal to the difference in the kinetic energies at the end and beginning.

Now think of turning a wrench attached to a bolt. If you use a longer wrench you have to move the handle by a longer arc length to achieve the same rotation  of the bolt. In other words, suppose you have to spend $x$ amount of energy to tighten a bolt, you can spend that by applying a small force over a larger arc length using a long wrench, or you can do the same by applying a large force over a small arc length using a short wrench.

If you move the wrench by an angle $d\theta$, then that means you have added $x$ amount of energy to the system. Regardless of whether you did it with a long or a short wrench. So if you "Have to" use a smaller wrench then in order to be able to cause the turn you have to generate enough force that the $x$ amount of energy will get added. The smaller you make the wrench the larger the force you will have to generate in order to add the same amount of energy. That is the thing you must hold on to. You have to add that $x$ amount of energy to be able to cause the $d\theta$ turn. And then you vary the $r$ and the $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is to angular momentum what force is to linear momentum. If you are looking for a mathematical answer and comfortable accepting angular momentum for what it is, then torque is just the time derivative of angular momentum and its expression as the distance-force product can be seen as a direct consequence of that.

The angular momentum of a system is
$$\vec L = \int \vec r \times  \vec v\ dm$$
so the torque on this system is
$$\vec \tau = \frac{d\vec L}{dt}=\int \vec v \times  \vec v\ dm+\int \vec r \times  \vec a\ dm=\int \vec r \times  \vec a\ dm=\int \vec r \times  d\vec F$$
where $d\vec F=\vec a\ dm$ is the net force on the infinitesimal mass $dm$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider half open door.
You will find that to fully open the door you will need to apply a force on it because of frictional forces acting at the hinges.
Furthermore as you try opening the door closer an close to the hinges you will find that you have to push harder (apply a larger force).
At the hinge let's assume that there is a constant frictional force $F_{\rm hinge}$ acting at a distance $r_{\rm hinge}$.
The work done in moving the door through an angle $\theta$ is $F_{\rm hinge}\,r_{\rm hinge}\, \theta$.
So to move the door you have to do some work, $F_{\rm you}\,r_{\rm you}\, \theta$ where $F_{\rm you}$ is the force that you apply and  $r_{\rm you}$ is the distance from the axis of rotation that you apply the force.

$F_{\rm hinge}\,r_{\rm hinge}\, \theta = F_{\rm you}\,r_{\rm you}\, \theta$ and since $r_{\rm you}> r_{\rm hinge}$ this means that $F_{\rm you}<F_{\rm hinge}$.